# Alternated Caesar Cipher

Tags: php, algorithm, php5, caesar-cipher

I've recently picked up PHP, for the first assignment in my IT-security class I decided to code it in PHP. 
The algorithm is an alternation of the Caesar cipher, instead of using a fixed number to push the letters a keyword is applied to rearrange a couple of letters and then move the rest of the letters accordingly.

I am pretty sure there can be improvements in string usage and probably also in the algorithm?
Any ideas and notes on programming style and such are very welcome.

Code:
https://github.com/TheLML/encrypt/blob/master/encrypt.php

or:

```
<?php
   class encrypt
   {
      private $key;
      private $uword;
      private $eword;
      private $letters;

      /**
       * Constructor.
       * 
       * Creates the $letters array.
       */
      function __construct()
      {
         for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
         {
            $this->letters[$i][0] = chr(65+$i);
            $this->letters[$i][1] = 0;
         }

         for($i=26;$i<52;$i++)
         {
            $this->letters[$i][0] = chr(97+$i-26);
            $this->letters[$i][1] = 0;
         }

         for($i=52;$i<62;$i++)
         {
            $this->letters[$i][0] = $i-52;
            $this->letters[$i][1] = 0;
         }

         $this->letters[62][0] = ' ';
         $this->letters[62][1] = 0;
      }

      /**
       * Encrypts the key using an alternation of the caesar cipher.
       * The key is used to set a different alternation for the letters, instead
       * of having it moved by a constant number.
       * 
       * @throws Exception - if there is no key
       * @return string - returns the encrypted alphabet as array
       */
      private function _encrypt()
      {
         if(empty($this->key))
         {
            throw new Exception("Empty key: cannot create encryption without a key.");
         }

         $key = $this->key;
         $letters = $this->letters;

         $encryption = array_fill(0, 63, '');
         $pos = 0;

         //add key to encoding. each letter only once, though
         for($i=0;$i<strlen($key);$i++)
         {
            $c = substr($key, $i, 1);
            $do = true;

            //only add letter if it hasn't been used yet
            for($j=0;$j<count($encryption);$j++)
            {
               if(!strcmp($encryption[$j], $c)) $do=false;
            }

            if($do) $encryption[$pos] = $c;

            //find letters that have already been used
            for($j=0;$j<63;$j++)
            {
               if(!strcmp($letters[$j][0], $encryption[$pos]))
               {
                  $letters[$j][1] = 1;
               }
            }  
            if($do) $pos++;
         }

         //add all the unused letters to the encoding array
         $k=63;
         for($i=$pos;$i<63;$i++)
         {
            $continue=true;
            for($j=63-$k;$j<63 && $continue;$j++)
            {
               if($letters[$j][1]==0)
               {
                  $encryption[$i] = $letters[$j][0];
                  $letters[$j][1] = 1;
                  $continue = false;
                  --$k;
               }
            }
         }

         //reset letter's usage
         for($i=0;$i<63;$i++)
         {
            $this->letters[$i][1] = 0;
         }  
         return $encryption;
      }

      /**
       * Encrypts the given word.
       * 
       * @throws Exception - if there is no unencrypted word
       * @return string - Encrypted word
       */
      public function encrypt()
      {
         if(empty($this->uword))
         {
            throw new Exception("Empty word: cannot encrypt a non-existend word.");
         }

         $encryption = $this->_encrypt();
         $uword = $this->uword;
         $eword = '';
         $letters = $this->letters;

         for($i=0;$i<strlen($uword);$i++)
         {
            $c = substr($uword, $i, 1);

            for($j=0;$j<63;$j++)
            {
               if(!strcmp($letters[$j][0], $c))
               {
                  $eword .= $encryption[$j];
               }
            }
         }  
         $this->eword = $eword;
         return $eword;
      }

      /**
       * Decrypts the given encryption.
       *
       * @throws Exception - if there is no encrypted word
       * @return string - Encrypted word
       */
      public function decrypt()
      {
         if(empty($this->eword))
         {
            throw new Exception("Empty encryption: cannot decrypt a non-existend word.");
         }

         $encryption = $this->_encrypt();
         $eword = $this->eword;
         $uword = '';
         $letters = $this->letters;

         for($i=0;$i<strlen($eword);$i++)
         {
            $c = substr($eword, $i, 1);

            for($j=0;$j<63;$j++)
            {
               if(!strcmp($encryption[$j], $c))
               {
                  $uword .= $letters[$j][0];
               }
            }
         }    
         $this->uword = $uword;   
         return $uword;
      }

      /**
       * 
       * @param unknown_type $key - keyword for encryption
       */
      public function setKey($key)
      {
         $this->key = $key;
      }

      /**
       * 
       * @param unknown_type $uword - unencrypted word
       */
      public function setUword($uword)
      {
         $this->uword = $uword;
      }

      /**
       * 
       * @param unknown_type $eword - encrypted word
       */
      public function setEword($eword)
      {
         $this->eword = $eword;
      }

      /**
       *
       * @return - $key
       */
      public function getKey()
      {
         return $this->key;
      }

      /**
       *
       * @return - $uword
       */
      public function getUword()
      {
         return $this->uword;
      }
      /**
       *
       * @return - $eword
       */
      public function getEword()
      {
         return $this->eword;
      }  
   }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE. Please have a look at the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq . Among other things, please make sure you include your code in the question. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

Give the class a better name... a noun makes more sense than a verb.

Consider simply removing the `$uword` and `$eword` properties and applicable setter methods. Instead, your encrypt method signature could be:

```
/**
 * @param string $uword word to encrypt
 * @return string encrypted word
 */
public function encrypt($uword)
...
```

Do the same with decrypt:

```
/**
 * @param string $eword word to decrypt
 * @return string decrypted word
 */
public function decrypt($eword)
...
```

Put a $key argument in the constructor:

```
public function __construct($key)
{
    $this->key  = $key;
    ...
```

With the $key invariant satisfied, no need to throw an exception if not set. Remove the setKey/getKey methods (unless you really need them).

Cleaner calling code example:

```
$cipher = new CeaserCipher('my key, get this from where ever');
$encryptedValue = $cipher->encrypt('foo');

$decryptedValue = $cipher->decrypt($encryptedValue);
```

Comment: thanks for your input, I will consider all of this in future projects.
Funnily enough, when I eventually implemented it into Qt C++ using QByteArrays and its methods the code shrunk from this massive size to just a couple of lines.